# Есть ли способ создать вторую страницу в приложении на Python с использованием модуля tkinter, кроме применения pack_forget() для каждого виджета?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я создавал MP3-плеер на Python c использованием модуля tkinter. Хотел сделать список музыкальных альбомов. При нажатии на один из альбомов, планировал открывать "вторую страницу" со списком песен в данном альбоме. Но способов сделать это без простого использования pack_forget() для каждого виджета в гугле не нашел. Возможно, неправильно искал. Я не хотел использовать pack_forget(), т.к. кнопки албомов в списке создаются в цикле, т.е. кнопки не получают уникальных названий, из-за чего я не могу пользоваться данным методом. Пожалуйста, посоветуйте мне что-нибудь

Comment: Собирайте каждую страницу во frame и используйте pack_forget для фрейма целиком.

Comment: Спасибо большое